1990s near-future space construction story - with inept spy
Published in Asimovs by someone like Allen Steele. It's a story the main character is telling to a friend about who he and his space construction coworkers messed with a guy who was hired to spy out subversive activity at the space construction facility. At one point in the story the friend asks how the narrator could possibly know what the spy was thinking and explained that the spy had at least once torn up his notes and dropped them in a toilet - but forgot to flush

"Free Beer and the William Casey Society" by Allen Steele, Asimov's, February 1989.  You have a good memory.

"Remember those coded messages he was sending to Baltimore? Lenny would write them down first in plain English, then rewrite them into code on the same page. Once he memorized the coded message, he would tear up the page and dump the scraps into the toilet in his bunkhouse. But the moron forgot to flush the pot one day."


Thank you so much.  That's a little earlier than I expected (and it's not in the complete list of his short fiction, only under the series name, which is why I missed it in ISFDB)

I do have a good memory, but evidently not quite good enough to remember every title I'm looking for...
